# How to safely close socket after BeginAccept(..)?

Tags: c#, sockets

This code represents actions of server:

```
private Socket _listenSocket;

        public event EventHandler Accept;

        protected virtual void OnAccept(ListenEventArgs args)
        {
            EventHandler handler = Accept;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, args);
        }
    public void Start()
            {
                StillListen = true;

                _listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                var localEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), _port);
                _listenSocket.Bind(localEp);
                _listenSocket.Listen(100);

                AcceptClient();
            }

            public void Stop()
            {
                StillListen = false;
                //_listenSocket.EndAccept();
                _listenSocket.Dispose();

            }

            private void AcceptClient()
            {
                _listenSocket.BeginAccept(Accepted, null);
            }

            private void Accepted(IAsyncResult result)
            {
                var client = _listenSocket.EndAccept(result);
                if (StillListen)
                {
                    _listenSocket.BeginAccept(Accepted, null);
                    OnAccept(new ListenEventArgs(client));
                }
            }
```

If I want to stop the listener, how can I do this? _listenSocket is still wait for accept clients, but after dispose of _listenSocket fires exception:
Access to disposed object not possible (inside void Accepted).

Please, help.

Comment: there are some examples of this same issue on `SO` please safe  yourself the waiting time and do a google search as well as checkout the link to a possible duplicate

Comment: Thanks, I did`n found that solution.